# Loading multiple images using http request GWT

Tags: gwt

I need to load about 400-500 images to the on single page at a time. Is there a quick way of doing so. I can, in fact, load the images using a for loop but that takes very long?

Many thanks in advance
Umesh

Comment: What's the average image size (width x height)? Maybe you can client bundle that...

Comment: Hi, i tried by using client bundle image resources as well! it still taking too long time... the average image size is not more than 400*600....one more thing is its loading properly within all the major browsers except IE9. in IE9 its taking more than 2 minutes too load whereas in other browsers it loads within a seconds! please suggest!

Answer (score 1):

As IE  is very slow in rendering...please do not add  all the images at a time...

As you mentioned the size of images in comment  user cannot see all the images at a time..so he must scroll down to see remaining images ...so why can't we use scroll event...

At the first shot loop the first set of images (let say 50)  ..from then you can use window scroll event ..

On scrolling you can append next set of 50 images...

This will increase the document load time...not only in internet explorer but also in remaining browsers...

Comment: Thanks Suresh for your response!